# Creating a base controller with autowired-functionality in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I'm really new to spring but it's okay. I have to set up a spring mvc rest app, that gets some data from a javafx application via `SpringApplicationBuilder.properties()`. (This is because I have to implement some libs of the gov that are really a pita...).

So I want all rest mvc controllers to extend an Base- or AppController. In this controller (within its constructor), I would like to access the SourceProperties via

`@Autowired 
Environment env`

But it's just null, when my AppController is static. When it's public, spring throws a BeanCreationException (Error creating bean with name 'appController' -> but I don't know how to handle this).

I hope, you can help me. Here is my last approach...

**Application.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Login = doLogin();
   Map<String, Object> p = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   p.put("Server", Server);
   p.put("Login", Login)";
}
```

**AppController.java**

```
@Controller
abstract class AppController {

    @Autowired
    Environment env

    public Login Login;

    public AppContoller() {
        //Access env and read Properties-Map and "Login"
        this.Login = .....;
    }
}
```

**DummyController.java**

```
@RestController
public class dummyController extends AppController {
    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public dummy greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return this.Login.SessionKey;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, many thanks in advance. I hope, my idea is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Your exception stack-trace :

> Error creating bean with name 'appController'

It is not possible to create an object of an abstract class. If you want a common functionality among all your controllers you can create *one* abstract class and then ask *each* controller to extend it.

```
public abstract class AbstractResultController {
 // some common functionality

}
```

Note there is no annotation on `AbstractResultController` and after that :

```
@Controller
public class AppController extends AbstractResultController {

}
```

[This](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-abstract-controller-example/) link will get you started.

---

**EDIT :**

Create a file like below to contain your Login details annotated with `@Configuration`

```
@Configuration
public abstract class Details {

    @Bean(name = "login")
    @Scope("singleton")
    public Login getLogin() {
        Login login = new Login();
        // populate login object as required
        return login
    }
}
```

Now you can access this bean/object anywhere, for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext absContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Details.class, Login.class);
    Login login = (Login) absContext.getBean("login");
}
```

OR

```
@RestController
public class dummyController  {

   @Autowired
   Login login;

   // Rest of the controller logic
   @RequestMapping("/greeting")
   public dummy greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
      return this.login.SessionKey;
   }

}
```

Comment: Many thanks, but that way, all Controllers have to set the login-object itself to the AppController. I wanted the AppController to receive/read the Login-env-object, set it to its public Property and propagate this that way to its inherited controllers. But somehow, I can't access `@Autowired Environment env` from the Appcontroller. I read your link and tried it (regarding my goal) without no luck. Or did I something wrong?

Comment: Haven't tried it out but, you can create a class and annotate it with `@Configuration` and expose a `@Bean` with all required details of login. Thus now you wouldn't need the abstract class after all.

Comment: Thanks, tried some approaches. That way, it seems that I have to set login from main() of Application.java. Is that possible/correct? Can you please give me an example? That would be really helpful. If I could access/share the bean from main() with the spring-Application, that would exactly what I need. Else, I would have to transport the login to the spring-application and in some (or each?) controller I would have to set the login from SourceProperty if it hasn't already be set. Correct?

Comment: For better understanding, this has to be the app "workflow": Main -> doLogin() -> after Login create spring application with passed login-object -> use login() within all mvc controllers. (The login is from foreign lib (javafx))

Comment: Not entirely sure if I got the exact requirement, but I've edited my answer hope it helps.

Comment: Hey thanks, this kinda helps. But I noticed, that the bean or login-object will be re-constructed, so it loses data. It must be a singleton, once created in SpringBoot (or main)-context. I'm struggling with that, but I come closer. Thanks so far for your help.

Comment: You can annotate the bean to be a singleton using `@Scope("singleton")`

Comment: Yes, tried that after your post, but didn't get it to work. It re-instantiates itself all the time. I run out of ideas, or maybe I'm blocked today.

Comment: What do you mean re-instantiates itself all the time?

Comment: Every time, I call getBean() from a controller, a new Login-Object is being created (tested by letting the ctor of Login write a random number to the console) and returned. So the original login-object from the third party lib (session and so on) is being dropped.

Comment: Hmm I doubt that is the case. You can try to print out the object I'm sure it's returning the same object as that is what @Singleton does.

Comment: Tested. It does. I copy&pasted your code. Here's a gist of the code. I hope, I do something wrong. https://gist.github.com/TheMiller2015/2a751a590ff236b787654ab52e968c49

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183053/discussion-between-nicholas-k-and-mikeross).

Comment: Thanks, I tried. Inside the MVC Controllers the bean is indeed a singleton. But it can't be accessed from Application.java main-Method (NullPointerException). And furthermore, the main method has to be static (could this also be a problem?). And when I inherit my Controllers from AppController, the AppController also can't access the bean via @Autowired (or else). It only work, when there is no inheritance of the mvcs (means no AppController) and only within the scope of the mvcs, not within Application.java main().

Comment: 1. Main method is always static. 2. I don't think its right to mix spring and javafx. Maybe you need to revisit the design?

Comment: Maybe you're right. But the javafx part (complete login) is given by the libs of the government. The data, I receive will be processed in an other application. So I wanted to expose this data via a rest api. Or is it possible to make two java applications (one fx and one mvc) and to transfer the Login Object? The gov libs are kind of an outsider. As I told, really pita...

Comment: You could use REST. But probably I'm not the right person to make that decision for you primarily because I'll need to understand the exact functionality, domain of the appl's, etc. You'll need to take an opinion of someone who's worked in both systems to correctly analyze the impact and act accordingly.

Comment: That's correct. It's a cardreader login with popup. that's the problem. But no problem, i'll try other approaches and read through other solutions. Nevertheless, you helped me a lot and I'm very thankful. If I get this method to work, i'll let you know.